# SWT window don't show components until maximizing

Tags: java, swt

I'm just learning SWT and I have some problems. I have a menu, in which there are two elements "File" and "Help". In File there are two items "Open File" and "Exit"

Once file is loaded (using "Open File"), it should print a Combo and a Label, but it doesn't show up, unless I resize window (or maximize). What I'm doing wrong?

**Open Display**

```
public Shell open (Display display) {
    this.display = display;
    initResources(); 
    this.shell = new Shell(display);

    createShellContents(); 

    shell.open();
    return shell;
}
```

**Menus**

```
public void createShellContents() { 
    shell.setText(getResourceString("window.title"));
    shell.setImage(appIcon);

    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Menu bar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    shell.setMenuBar(bar);

    createFileMenu(bar);
    createHelpMenu(bar);
}
```

Once file is open and loaded (it works), I try to create both Combo and Label

```
private void createLayout () { 
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
    gridLayout.marginHeight = gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL);
    gridData.widthHint = 185;
    createComboView(shell, gridData);

    Label numObjectsLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_FILL);
    gridData.widthHint = 185;
    numObjectsLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);
    numObjectsLabel.setText("Sample");
}

private void createComboView(Composite parent, Object layoutData) {

    Label labelGame = new Label(parent, 0);
    labelGame.setText("Game: ");


    combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.NONE);
    combo.setLayoutData(layoutData);

    String[] gamesStr = null;
    if (games != null && !games.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Games has " + games.size());

        gamesStr = new String[games.size()]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) { 
            gamesStr[i]= "GAME " + String.valueOf(games.get(i).getId());
        }

        combo.setItems(gamesStr);
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("NO GAMES");
    }

    combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            int k = combo.getSelectionIndex(); 

            System.out.println("Selected" + k);

        }
    });
}
```

This is how it looks (after load a file and maximize, or resize, window):

[image: analyzer]

Besides, any mistake you see, please tell me. This is my first GUI program, I don't understand how layout works and how elements are shown. I want a row (where combo is) to show some information, and once an item is selected, paint the window, not sure which Layout should I use. I'd probably ask another question for this.

PD: It looks like the image cannot be loaded (don't know why), but it always fails. Here's a link: http://s28.postimg.org/4v7k34dzx/Analyzer.png

Comment: You can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29 to let Swing resize your UI to its components.

Comment: @m4mbax This is SWT not Swing

Comment: SWT should also have a pack() on Shell :S Sorry for not pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add or change controls on a shell after it has been opened you need to redo the layout and recalculate the shell size. Something like:

```
shell.layout(true, true);

shell.pack();
```

Comment: It worked. I see `pack()` also resizes windows, which I don't want, but `shell.layout()` is perfect. Thanks.